# ZF2 - How can I do Aggregate functions in a Select?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2

Converting one of my applications from procedural to ZF2 and am copying across the SQL. I'm adding pagination so need to use `Zend\Db\Sql\Select`. 
I've got a database which orders how well users are doing and need to use Aggregate functions but can't see anything in the documentation or code about it.

I have `SUM()` and `COUNT()` that I need to use in my query for a long list of users (so can't just do a separate one for each row)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Found this and it works fine: `'total_stuff' => new Expression('SUM(table.stuff)')`